# Desktop Excel addin (part of Office 365 subscription) still using IE11 webview when using shared javascript runtime, why?

Tags: office-js

It is almost inevitable you need to run your addin in a shared javascript runtime environment between your addin and custom functions. Certain information needs to be shared between the two. This is all fine when running the web version of Excel in Office 365 since the addin uses the browser you are running excel in.

However for the desktop version of Excel (linked to Office 365 subscription) it should use Edge as the embedded browser but for some reason as soon as you use a shared runtime it reverts to using IE11 which is extremely painful. I'm using modern javascript and web components etc and trying to get this polyfilled and transpiled into ES5 is just not pleasant.

So why does desktop Excel use IE11 in shared runtime mode and is it possible to force it back to using Edge at the very least?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, see footnote 3 in this article: [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins). There is no way to override this behavior. You must use a polyfill or transpile.

Comment: I should of mentioned I'm aware of the footnote but I want to know why? It's a big deal that using the latest and greatest Excel office 365 on desktop that it still uses IE11 when a shared runtime is used. I'm hoping this dependency on IE11 will be removed in the near future, cheers